# Plotting between two columns of a data table

Tags: plotting

I want to plot between the 3rd and 4th column data points of a data table. I used the command:

```
`data[[All,{3,4}]]`
```

but it gives output as:
`"Part {3,4} of \!\({\"0.2, 1, 3.0911369616623223, \ -2.809807813209614\"}\) does not exist"`
I can't figure out what's wrong. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Try: `data[[All, 3 ;; 4]]` and lookup `Span` in the docs.

Comment: The community is happy to help you, but we may not want to keep this question open for long after you solved your problem. Therefore, your question may be [closed](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it is technically [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD). That is because it arises from a simple mistake easily found in the documentation and we curate questions that may help future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. This and your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2):

## Your error

This is a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) with a single item that is a [`String`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html).

```
datastring = {"0.2, 1, 3.0911369616623223,  -2.809807813209614"}
(* {0.2, 1, 3.0911369616623223,  -2.809807813209614} *)
```

You can't take items that don't exist.

[image]

## 1D

This is a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) with 4 numbers, that is a 1D data set.

```
data1d = {0.2, 1, 3.0911369616623223,  -2.809807813209614}
(* {0.2,1,3.09114,-2.80981} *)
```

Take [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) like this

```
data1d[[3;;4]]
(* {3.09114,-2.80981} *)
```

## 2D

This is a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of `List`s, that is a $9\times 9$ 2D matrix.

```
data2d = Table[a+b/10.,{a,9},{b,9}]
(* {{1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9},
    {2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9},
    {3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9},
    {4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9},
    {5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9},
    {6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9},
    {7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9},
    {8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9},
    {9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9}} *)
```

Take columns $3$ and $4$ like this

```
data2d[[All,3;;4]]
(* {{1.3,1.4},{2.3,2.4},{3.3,3.4},{4.3,4.4},{5.3,5.4},{6.3,6.4},{7.3,7.4},{8.3,8.4},{9.3,9.4}} *)
```